# Providing Angular "ErrorHandler" in AppModule cause "Cannot find module" in lazy child module routing

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a general question about how Angular works, for the moment I do not know if it is a bug in "ng serve" or an internal mechanism to Angular that I would not understood.

My project contains different modules loaded from App Component> Layout Component> [other lazy modules]

Here is an excerpt from the structure:
[app modules tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdQ6W.png)

Ant the routing for layout component:

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LayoutComponent } from './layout.component';
import {AuthGuard} from '../auth/guards/auth-guard';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../home/home.module#HomeModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../admin/admin.module#AdminModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../campaigns/campaigns.module#CampaignsModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../campaigns/campaigns.module#CampaignsModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../channels/channels.module#ChannelsModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../users/users.module#UsersModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../visualizer/visualizer.module#VisualizerModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../agency/agency.module#AgencyModule' },
      { path: '', loadChildren: '../publisher/publisher.module#PublisherModule' }
    ]
  }
];

export const LayoutRoutingModule = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

I have never had any problem with routing since the beginning of the project.
Recently I wanted to integrate an ErrorHandler in my application at the AppModule level.

My AppModule:

```
@Injectable()
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {

  }
  handleError(error: Error) {
    const angulartics2GoogleAnalytics = this.injector.get(Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics);

    if (environment.production === false) {
      console.error(error);
    }

    angulartics2GoogleAnalytics.exceptionTrack({fatal: false, description: error.name + ' ' + error.stack});
  }
}


export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './vendors/lang/', '.json');
}
declare const require;
export function translationsFactory(localData: string) {
  localData = localData || 'en'; // default to english if no locale
  return require(`raw-loader!../locale/messages.${localData}.xlf`);
}
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    FormsModule,
    AuthModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    LayoutModule,
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production }),
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js'),
    SharedMaterialModule,
    PopoverModule.forRoot(),
    Angulartics2Module.forRoot([Angulartics2GoogleAnalytics], {
      developerMode: false,//!environment.production,
      pageTracking: {
        clearQueryParams: false,
        clearIds: true,
        idsRegExp: new RegExp('^[0-9a-fA-F]{24}$')
      }
    }),
    MomentModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      }
    }),
    CookieModule.forRoot(),
    BsDropdownModule.forRoot(),
    SharedModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LayoutComponent,
    PreloaderDirective,
    AppHeaderComponent,
    AppSidenavComponent,
    ToggleOffcanvasNavDirective,
    AutoCloseMobileNavDirective,
    AppSidenavMenuComponent,
    AccordionNavDirective,
    AppendSubmenuIconDirective,
    HighlightActiveItemsDirective,
    AppCustomizerComponent,
    ToggleQuickviewDirective,
    AppFooterComponent,
    AppSearchOverlayComponent,
    SearchOverlayDirective,
    OpenSearchOverlaylDirective,
  ],
  exports: [
    TranslateModule,
    CookieModule
  ],
  providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy},
    {provide: TRANSLATIONS_FORMAT, useValue: 'xlf'},
    {provide: MISSING_TRANSLATION_STRATEGY, useValue: MissingTranslationStrategy.Error},
    {provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr'},
    {
      provide: TRANSLATIONS,
      useFactory: translationsFactory,
      deps: [LOCALE_ID]
    },
    AuthService,
    AlertService,
    MessagingService,
    TourGuideService,
    I18n,
    /*
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}
    */
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {
  constructor(public appRef: ApplicationRef) {}
  hmrOnInit(store) {
  }
  hmrOnDestroy(store) {
    const cmpLocation = this.appRef.components.map((cmp) => cmp.location.nativeElement);
    // recreate elements
    store.disposeOldHosts = createNewHosts(cmpLocation);
    // remove styles
    removeNgStyles();
  }
  hmrAfterDestroy(store) {
    // display new elements
    store.disposeOldHosts();
    delete store.disposeOldHosts;
  }
}
```

If I provide the service when I have not cut the ng serve process, everything works, but when I cut ng serve and restart it, the compilation works but when loading the page I have the error:

```
"Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot find module '../home/home.module'."
```

Deleting this single line is enough to correct the problem:

```
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler}
```

Can someone enlighten me on this obscure problem? I have not found any similar question in my many Google search or Stack Overflow

This is the first question related to Angular for which I have not found a solution in almost 3 years, congratulations to Angular team!

Thank you in advance to the whole community :)

(Sorry for my poor English)

Comment: Hi :)


Sorry, I deleted unnecessary images.
Is this information sufficient in your opinion?


Thanks for the advice ;)

Comment: Much better! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "export" to your ErrorHandler class:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
    ...
}
```

Comment: That was it ! Thanks ibanfq ! :)